# Trouble understanding the usage of external libraries in a java project/IntelliJ

Tags: java, module, intellij-idea, classpath, libraries

Now that I've learned a bit more, I can ask a more direct question.

Scenario:
I have a Java project in `IntelliJ Idea`, with the end goal of making a standalone .jar capable of running on Windows or Linux, either run from the command line with `java -jar jarname.jar` or simply by being double-clicked like any normal, simple jar.

I've written a handful of classes, located in my `src/package/name` directory.  However, one of my classes requires the use of an external class, i.e. a class not located in my source directory or is not part of Java's default set of `.jar`'s in the `JDK`.

How do I go about configuring `IntelliJ` to build the `.jar` artifact AND include the necessary resources inside of it, with everything needed put in the proper place, so that *my* class can use the resource by an ordinary `import` statement?  An answer given in example form would be awesome; I've almost figured it out, but there must be just one thing I'm not doing correctly.

Thanks for your time,

Yankee

> Sources:
>
> http://tukaani.org/xz/java.html
>
> Viewing the directory structure of that source gives a better idea:
>
> http://git.tukaani.org/?p=xz-java.git;a=tree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## One does not simply package Mordor into their jar.

After much experimentation, I found a solution that, while maybe not the right way to do it, definitely works.  The key is to:

1. Define your external library (a .jar in my case) as a module dependency.
2. Add your external resources as (what IntelliJ calls) an "Extracted Directory."

For the first item, go to File -> Project Structure.  Click "Modules" in the Project Settings list on the left.  In the list just to the right, you will see a list of modules (whatever they are) which belong to your project.  Leave that alone, but make sure that it is highlighted/selected as the current module.  What you want is the settings for that module, which will show in the window on the right.  Go to the "Dependencies" tab.  On the rightmost part of the screen will be a little green plus sign.  Click that, choose "Jars or directories" and navigate to your relevant resource you want to bring along with your finished jar.

#### Note: don't be fooled by the check box that says "Export."  Its only purpose is to cause endless pain and suffering as you wonder why the dependency isn't exported along with your jar.  Always remember, the export box is trying to get you to click on it.  It *wants* to be ticked   :3

Next, add that resource as an extracted directory by going to File -> Project Structure.  Then "Artifacts" in the Project Settings list on the left.  Click the green plus sign at the top to make a new "Jar" artifact "From modules with dependencies."  In the right hand window, under the "Output Layout" tab, click the little green plus sign and choose "Extracted Directory."  Once again, browse to your precious jar.

You should now be able to successfully build a jar artifact that contains all the resources it needs to run as you designed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference section on configuring external libraries as module dependencies - [link](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html). Regarding artifacts construction - it's possible to precisely specify its content (including dependency libraries content) - [link](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-artifacts.html).

Comment: It's also possible to [configure the executable jar artifact with all the module dependencies](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/).

Comment: Thanks for the links, guys.  Before I figured out how to do it, I came across the first of denis's links.  However, it won't actually work until you additionally perform the instructions in CrazyCoder's link.

Answer (score 0):

Read [How classes are found...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html)

It is OK (expected that you) to ship your program in your own jar, and dependent 'libraries' as separate jars

You are expected to provide a way to run your program with the correct -classpath argument to the java command so that java can find both your jar, and the dependent jars... there are multiple ways to do that... see the link above.

Rolf

Comment: Thanks for that link.  While it doesn't solve my problem, I now know a lot more than I used to about how the JVM fetches what it needs.